# Highlighting the selected row in a table using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How to write the directive to highlight the selected row in a table,

I have 20 plus tables and i need to write a common function for this table.

I am writing the same code in controllers,

```
$scope.selectedRow = null;
$scope.rowHighilited = function(row){
  $scope.selectedRow = row;
};
<table>
<tr>
<th>
  first row
</th>
</tr>
<tr data-ng-click="rowHighilited($index)">row1</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

JS:

```
  $scope.selectedRow = null;
  $scope.rowHighilited = function (idSelected) {
     $scope.selectedRow = idSelected;
  };
```

HTML :

```
  <tr ng-repeat="row in rows" ng-click="rowHighilited(row.id)" ng-class="{selected: row.id === selectedRow}">
    <td> ...</td>
  </tr>
```

You can learn more in the [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) documentation

Comment: I am using similar way, but i need to avoid multiple  times repeating the same code